# How can I inject HTML fetched from the back end into a react component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I would like to host some HTML on my back end that I can then insert into a react component.

I've tried solutions that involve using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but those are equally unsuccessful.

The basic idea is that I want to have a component, `Content`, that fetches some HTML and then returns a fragment with that HTML in it:

```js
export async function Content({ resourcePath }) {
  const response = await fetch(resourcePath, { method: 'GET' })
  const html = await response.text();

  return (
    <>
      {html}
    </>
  )
}
```

On the back end, I have routes set up on an Express server listening for `GET` requests on `resourcePath`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';

export const contentRouter = express.Router();

contentRouter.get('/content/homepage', (_, res) => {
  const data = fs.readFileSync("path/to/page.html");
  res.send(data.toString());
})
```

When I load a page that contains a `Content` component I'm able to log the raw HTML from the response, but the console barfs a ton of errors.

The error that I believe is most relevant is

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I suspect that the problem has something to do with Promises, namely that as my code is currently written the `Content` component tries to return a fragment that contains a Promise and not the resolved value.

If that's the case, how can I set the inner HTML of `Content` to the HTML returned from the fetch?

Comment: An async function **cannot** be a React component, as it returns a promise not an element. Otherwise dangerouslySet... should work fine if used correctly. Read up on hooks, fetching data asynchronously is a very common pattern and will be explained in any tutorial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Per @jonrsharpe's suggestion, I made the `Content` function synchronous:

```js
export function Content({ resourcePath }) {
  fetch(resourcePath, { method: 'GET' })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
      const content = document.querySelector('#content_container');
      content.innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  return (
    <>
      <span id="content_container"></span>
    </>
  )
}
```

It works, but it seems like a bit of a kludge. If you happen across this an know a solution that's more idiomatic, please feel free to post a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop on element , see docs for more info
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
export function Content({ resourcePath }) {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(resourcePath, { method: "GET" }).then((response) => {
      response.text().then((resultsHTML) => {
        setHtml(resultsHTML);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />;
}
```

Comment: as already pointed out in the comments, you cannot use an `async` function for a React component